# How to differentiate between double tap and single tap on react native?

Tags: react-native

I need to perform different action on single and double tap on a view. On double tap I need to like the image just like Instagram double tap experience. On single tap I need to open a modal.
For double tap I have used TapGestureHandler which works perfect

```
 <TapGestureHandler
          ref={this.doubleTapRef}
          maxDelayMs={200}
          onHandlerStateChange={this.onProductImageDoubleTap}
          numberOfTaps={2}
        >
         <SomeChildComponent ...
```

But when I add any Touchable to detect single tap in the

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.imageTapped}>
```

on double tapping the `this.imageTapped` function is called twice along with `this.onProductImageDoubleTap`. Is there any way to cancel tap on touchable when two taps are done is quick succession

Comment: They have an example in [github](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/master/Example/multitap/index.js) how to do this with `TapGestureHandler` :)

Answer (score 11):

**2022 update**

This is a performant native solution without any JS thread blocking calculation!
[Many more tips here](https://medium.com/swmansion/introducing-gesture-handler-2-0-50515f1c4afc)

```
const tap = Gesture.Tap()
  .numberOfTaps(2)
  .onStart(() => {
    console.log('Yay, double tap!');
  });

return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={tap}>
      {children}
    </GestureDetector>
);
```

Comment: const tap = Gesture.Tap()
  .numberOfTaps(2)
  .onEnd(() => {
   copyOrderDetails(item);
  });
Above code craches but console log is working

Comment: @AshishSingh Provide more information about your code please

Comment: Your code works fine with console.log but when I excute expo-clipboard's Clipboard.setStringAsync(text) inside onStart or onEnd it crashes

Comment: @AshishSingh I think because those methods is async. Maybe u should use 'runOnJS' method... Google it

Comment: Yes, they are async, Thanks!

Comment: For running async methods on double tap, use this: `const tap = Gesture.Tap()
    .numberOfTaps(2)
    .runOnJS(true)
    .onStart(() => {
      // async operation
    });`

Answer (score 10):

The best solution is not using state, since setting state is asynchronous.Works like a charm for me on android !

```
let lastPress = 0;
const functionalComp = () => {
    const onDoublePress = () => {
        const time = new Date().getTime();
        const delta = time - lastPress;

        const DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY = 400;
        if (delta < DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY) {
            // Success double press
            console.log('double press');

        }
        lastPress = time;
    };

    return <View
        onStartShouldSetResponder =
        {(evt) => onDoublePress()}>
     </View>
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is use `react-native-gesture-handler`

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler

Here is my solution -

```
import {State, TapGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
export const DoubleTap = ({children}: any) => {
  const doubleTapRef = useRef(null);

  const onSingleTapEvent = (event: any) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
      console.log("single tap 1");
    }
  };

  const onDoubleTapEvent = (event: any) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
       console.log("double tap 1");
    }
  };

  return (
    <TapGestureHandler
      onHandlerStateChange={onSingleTapEvent}
      waitFor={doubleTapRef}>
      <TapGestureHandler
        ref={doubleTapRef}
        onHandlerStateChange={onDoubleTapEvent}
        numberOfTaps={2}>
        {children}
      </TapGestureHandler>
    </TapGestureHandler>
  );
};
```

Now we will wrap the component where we need to detect the double and single tap : -

```
 <DoubleTap>
    <View>
      ...some view and text
    </View>
 </DoubleTap>
```

Answer (score 2):

With hooks:

```
const [lastPressed, setLastPressed] = useState(0);

const handlePress = useCallback(() => {
  const time = new Date().getTime();
  const delta = time - lastPressed;
  setLastPressed(time);
  if (lastPressed) {
    if (delta < DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY) {
      console.log('double press');
    } else {
      console.log('single press');
    }
  }
}, [lastPressed]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The package [react-native-double-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-double-tap) seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

since you are asking on handling one tap and double tap, here's a simple code i think should covered your issue

> Untested

first defined `clickCount:0` in state:

```
state={clickCount:0, //another state}
```

then create a function with `setTimeout` to handling if user tapping once or two times:

```
handlingTap(){
  this.state.clickCount==1 ?
  //user tap twice so run this.onProductImageDoubleTap()
  this.onProductImageDoubleTap :
  //user tap once so run this.imageTapped with setTimeout and setState
  //i set 1 sec for double tap, so if user tap twice more than 1 sec, it's count as one tap
  this.setState({clickCount:1}, ()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({clickCount:0})
      this.imageTapped()
    }, 1000)
  })
}

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handlingTap()}/>
```

just used `TouchableWithoutFeedback` instead of `TapGestureHandler`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified flix's answer into this. By this way, you can catch one and double click separately. I also changed debounce into 300ms which is fairly well for one and double click.

```
state={clickCount:0, //another state}
```

Binding context into the `handlingTap` method

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.handlingTap = this.handlingTap.bind(this)
}
```

With this function you can catch them separately

```
handlingTap() {
    this.state.clickCount === 1
        ? this.doubleClick() // This catches double click
        : this.setState(state => ({ clickCount: state.clickCount + 1 }), () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (this.state.clickCount !== 2) {
                    this.oneClick() // this catches one click
                }
                this.setState({ clickCount: 0 })
            }, 300)
        })
}
```

In the button you can use this way

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handlingTap}></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Easy 2024 typescript-safe variant with built-in Touchable Opacity

Usage:

```
<DoubleTouchableOpacity onPress={...} onDoublePress={...}>
  ...
</DoubleTouchableOpacity>
```

```
import { GestureResponderEvent, TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

const DEFAULT_DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY = 250

type Props = {
  onDoublePress?: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void
  doublePressDelay?: number
} & TouchableOpacityProps

const DoubleTouchableOpacity: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, onPress, onDoublePress, doublePressDelay = DEFAULT_DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY }) => {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0)
  const timeoutRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (timeoutRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
      }
    }
  }, [])

  const handlePress = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
    setClickCount((prev) => prev + 1)

    if (clickCount === 1) {
      if (timeoutRef.current != null) clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
      onDoublePress?.(event)
      setClickCount(0)
    } else {
      timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        if (onPress) onPress(event)
        setClickCount(0)
      }, doublePressDelay)
    }
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={handlePress}>
      {children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default DoubleTouchableOpacity
```